# Calling .text() with JQuery class selector returns one string instead of array

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve an array of strings with an JQuery class selector:

```
var foo = $( ".bar" ).text();
```

But this returns just one string, in which all elements are joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `PUSH` method:

```
var foo = [];    

$('.bar').each(function(){    
    foo.push($(this).text());
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5SGBL/

Answer (score 2):

If you want an array do this :

```
var foo = $( ".bar" ).map(function(){ return $(this).text() }).get();
```

The `get` at the end changes the object built by `map` into a normal native array.

Comment: I found another solution below. Do you think it is save?

Comment: My solution returns a fake array, I'll take yours ... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I found it by chance:

If you write a empty function as parameter, than JQuery returns an array instead of joined text.

```
var foo = $(".bar" ).text( function() {} );
```

Comment: In my tests it doesn't return an array of the elements texts.

Comment: I do not see array of text using this. It returns empty object. Not sure where did you find this but how could you expect to get something out of empty function?

Comment: I think it simply returns `$('.bar')` which, depending on how you look at it (an alert ?) might look a little like an array of the texts.

Comment: alert just returned empty object.